# Extracting info from button in Ruby

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have a line of code that links to a button on a HTML page and I'm wondering is there anyway that I can extract a specific value?

```
<input type="button" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="selector(item,012345)"<br />
```

Is there anyway that I can extract the number `012345` from the code above? 
My current attempt is:

```
temp = doc.xpath(//div....../input)
```

but that returns the raw data of the whole button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't tell how to select the right input without more context but in general you would do:

```
doc.at('input')[:onclick][/\d+/]
```